# "Stratify" parameter from sklearn's train_test_split not working correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have a problem with the `stratify` parameter in the `train_test_split()` function of scikit-learn. This is a dummy example with the same problem that appears randomly on my data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
train_test_split(a, stratify=a, random_state=42)
```

which returns:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0]]
```

Shouldn't it select a "1" also in the test subset? From how I expect `train_test_split()` with `stratify` to work it should return something like:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1]]
```

This happens with some values of `random_state`, while with other values it works correctly; but I cannot search for a "right" value of it every time I have to analyse data.

I have python 2.7 and scikit-learn 0.18.

Comment: What if you tried with `stratify=np.unique(a)`?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, because the list passed to `stratify` must be of the same length as the list to be split.

Comment: There are no place in the docs where it declares that there will be all classes even in a very small subset. If you add the only 1 to your list then you get class 1 in the test split. I think it should be the same part of class 1 as in your train split. For example, if you remove 'stratify' then you get the tail of your list instead of list with shuffled classes.

Answer (score 16):

This question was asked 8 months ago but I guess an answer might still help readers in the future.

When using the `stratify` parameter, `train_test_split` actually relies on the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` function to do the split. As you see in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html), `StratifiedShuffleSplit` does aim to do the split by preserving the percentage of samples for each class, as you expected.

The problem is, in your example 25% (2 of 8 samples) are 1s, but the sample size is not large enough for you to see this proportion reflected on the test set. You have two options here:

**A.** Increase the size of the test set with the option `test_size`, which defaults to 0.25, to say 0.5. In this case, half of your samples will become your test set, and you'll see that 25% of them (i.e. 1 in 4) are 1.

```
>>> a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> train_test_split(a, stratify=a, random_state=42, test_size=0.5)
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

**B.** Keep `test_size` to its default value and increase the size of your set `a` so that 25% of its samples amount to at least 4 elements. An `a` of 16 samples or more will do that for you.

```
>>> a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> train_test_split(a, stratify=a, random_state=42)
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very helpful!!